# Does the operating system matter when syncing?

Tags: sync

I'm going to buy a mobile phone with android and I have use linux as operating system on my desktop computers and laptop, as android is based on linux I could hope the compatibility with linux should be okay.

I've been distant from the mobile phone industry for some time, but I've seen that some phones use their own software, does android use an platform-dependant application to communicate with the phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android doesn't natively use any software to sync or perform syncs with your computer.  It syncs with your Google Account services in the cloud.  You can sync certain things with your computer in different ways and it all depends on what and how you are trying to sync, but generally, Linux machines work just fine with Android.

If you want more detailed answers try being more specific about what you want to do (sync your contacts with Thunderbird, or sync you music...).

Comment: can you give me some examples of common tasks?.. as sync contacts from thunderbird or sync music

Comment: @Vicfred If you have a specific question, please ask it, but StackExchange isn't meant for listing off random possibilities.

Comment: @Vicfred: That is a very open ended question.  I will say that you don't ever have to sync anything to your computer.  I use my computer and Droid very frequently but I never sync them because my Droid syncs everything I need with Google and then I can assess this stuff (Docs, Calendar, Email, Contacts, Reader...) all from Google.com when I'm on my computer.